# babel-cli issues with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I am using babel to build a part of my library and I'm running into issues when i run babel commands through npm.

I have an npm script called build that calls:

```
{
  "prebuild": "rm -rf && mkdir dist",
  "build": "babel src/index.js -o dist/index.js"
}
```

I have run the actual babel command itself in my command line and it works.

However when I do npm run build from my command line it says

```
The CLI has been moved into the package 'babel-cli'
```

npm also says that it is that specific line that is failing.

I have already tried the following:

1. Restart my terminal.
2. Install babel v5 because I read that v6 split a lot of its functionality.
3. npm rebuild.
4. Delete my node_modules and npm install

Any other ideas? as to why npm fails at running this command?

Comment: Do you have `babel-cli` installed? Try using `babel@5` and/or do `npm install -g babel-cli`

Comment: I initially did npm install -g babel-cli which installed v6. I couldn't even run the babel command with that. Then I did npm install -g babel@5, at that point I was able to run babel manually from my command line but I could not run my script from npm.

Comment: Try to install `babel@5` also in your local project...

Comment: That seemed to work...

I'm curious though why didn't it work when I did a global install?

Comment: You need it globally for some other stuff, but lock it as a package in the project will trigger it correctly; the same happens for `grunt-cli` (usually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `babel@5` globally (`npm install babel@5 --global`) as well as locally: `npm install babel@5 --save-dev`